# Normalizing data using Unpivot or Cross Apply in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, unpivot

I'm having trouble unpivoting some data. I see other examples on here for unpivoting tables but I have pairs which need unpivoted. There are actually 10+ disease/date pairs in my dataset, but I've chosen three pairs to simplify the example.

**Here's my source data:**

```
MRN      GUMCID     Event    BreastID  BreastDate  ColonID ColonDate    PancID  PancDate
2000012  90000001   event_1  42        1/1/2000    43      8/5/2014     44      8/6/2012
2008006  90000020   event_1  102       5/7/2003    103     9/11/2012        
2000012  90002002   event_1  900       8/5/2004    902     12/5/2009
2000012  90002002   event_2  1000      9/6/2006
```

**Here's what I need it converted to**:

```
MRN     GUMCID    Event     TissueType  Date        ID
2000012 90000001  event_1   BreastID    1/1/2000    42
2000012 90000001  event_1   ColonID     8/5/2014    43
2000012 90000001  event_1   PancID      8/6/2012    44
2008006 90000020  event_1   BreastID    5/7/2003    102
2008006 90000020  event_1   ColonID     9/11/2012   103
2000012 90002002  event_1   BreastID    8/5/2004    900
2000012 90002002  event_1   PancID      12/5/2009   902
2000012 90002002  event_2   BreastID    9/6/2006    1000
```

I've fumbled around with unpivot and cross apply and can't seem to make this work. Any thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: Where does the date for pancid come from?

Comment: It's there in the source data example, you have to scroll to the right to see it. It's in the PancDate column.

Comment: Ah sorry phones browser not displaying the scroll bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select mrd, gumcid, event, tissuetype, date, id
from tbl
cross apply (
    values 
        ('breastid', breastid, breastdate),
        ('colonid', colonid, colondate),
        ('pancid', pancid, pancdate)
) t(tissuetype, id, date)
where id is not null
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a simple way to pull in the BreastID/ColonID/PancID columns names to use as the TissueType value here rather than hard coding them?

Answer (score 3):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE 
(MRN INT, GUMCID INT, [Event] VARCHAR(10), BreastID INT, 
          BreastDate DATE, ColonID INT,  ColonDate DATE, PancID INT, PancDate DATE)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
(2000012,  90000001,'event_1',  42   ,'1/1/2000', 43  ,'8/5/2014' , 44 ,'8/6/2012'),
(2008006,  90000020,'event_1',  102  ,'5/7/2003', 103 ,'9/11/2012', NULL, NULL),       
(2000012,  90002002,'event_1',  900  ,'8/5/2004', 902 ,'12/5/2009', NULL, NULL),
(2000012,  90002002,'event_2',  1000 ,'9/6/2006', NULL, NULL      , NULL, NULL)
```

### Query

```
SELECT MRN
      ,GUMCID
      ,[Event]
      ,TissueType
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),
                  CASE 
                        WHEN TissueType = 'BreastID' THEN BreastDate
                        WHEN TissueType = 'ColonID'  THEN ColonDate
                        WHEN TissueType = 'PancID'   THEN PancDate
                   END, 103)   AS [Date]     
      ,ID
FROM @Table t
 UNPIVOT (ID FOR TissueType IN (BreastID, ColonID, PancID)
          )up
```

### Result

```
╔═════════╦══════════╦═════════╦════════════╦════════════╦══════╗
║   MRN   ║  GUMCID  ║  Event  ║ TissueType ║    Date    ║  ID  ║
╠═════════╬══════════╬═════════╬════════════╬════════════╬══════╣
║ 2000012 ║ 90000001 ║ event_1 ║ BreastID   ║ 01/01/2000 ║   42 ║
║ 2000012 ║ 90000001 ║ event_1 ║ ColonID    ║ 05/08/2014 ║   43 ║
║ 2000012 ║ 90000001 ║ event_1 ║ PancID     ║ 06/08/2012 ║   44 ║
║ 2008006 ║ 90000020 ║ event_1 ║ BreastID   ║ 07/05/2003 ║  102 ║
║ 2008006 ║ 90000020 ║ event_1 ║ ColonID    ║ 11/09/2012 ║  103 ║
║ 2000012 ║ 90002002 ║ event_1 ║ BreastID   ║ 05/08/2004 ║  900 ║
║ 2000012 ║ 90002002 ║ event_1 ║ ColonID    ║ 05/12/2009 ║  902 ║
║ 2000012 ║ 90002002 ║ event_2 ║ BreastID   ║ 06/09/2006 ║ 1000 ║
╚═════════╩══════════╩═════════╩════════════╩════════════╩══════╝
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a simple way to pull in the BreastID/ColonID/PancID columns names to use as the TissueType value here rather than hard coding them?